# install error for php7 on centos7

Tags: yum, centos7, php-7

Reference Document : https://webtatic.com/packages/php70/

PHP 7.0.0 has been released on PHP.net on 3rd December 2015, and is also available for CentOS/RHEL 6.7 and 7.1 at Webtatic via Yum in it’s testing repository.

I have the following error during php7 install:

```
[root]# yum install php70w php70w-opcache

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.riken.jp
 * epel: ftp.riken.jp
 * extras: ftp.riken.jp
 * updates: ftp.riken.jp
 * webtatic: sp.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php70w.x86_64 0:7.0.0-1.w6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php70w-common(x86-64) = 7.0.0-1.w6 for package: php70w-7.0.0-1.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php70w-cli(x86-64) = 7.0.0-1.w6 for package: php70w-7.0.0-1.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php70w-cli = 7.0.0-1.w6 for package: php70w-7.0.0-1.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20051115 for package: php70w-7.0.0-1.w6.x86_64
---> Package php70w-opcache.x86_64 0:7.0.0-1.w6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php70w.x86_64 0:7.0.0-1.w6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20051115 for package: php70w-7.0.0-1.w6.x86_64
---> Package php70w-cli.x86_64 0:7.0.0-1.w6 will be installed
---> Package php70w-common.x86_64 0:7.0.0-1.w6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libgmp.so.3()(64bit) for package: php70w-common-7.0.0-1.w6.x86_64
--> Processing Conflict: php70w-common-7.0.0-1.w6.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.5.0
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php70w-7.0.0-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           Requires: httpd-mmn = 20051115
           Installed: httpd-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.1.x86_64 (@updates)
               httpd-mmn = 20120211
               httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664
               httpd-mmn = 20120211-x86-64
           Available: httpd-2.4.6-31.el7.centos.x86_64 (base)
               httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664
               httpd-mmn = 20120211-x86-64
               httpd-mmn = 20120211
Error: php70w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-36.el7_1.x86_64
Error: Package: php70w-common-7.0.0-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           Requires: libgmp.so.3()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

How can I install php7 on centOS7?

Comment: It's never a good idea to install an older package. If you really need the older `php` which requires an older `httpd-mmn`, try `yum downgrade php70w-7.0.0-1.w6.x86_64`. If this doesn't work, try downgrading `httpd*` first. Or try replacing php. Last resort is to remove the installed `php` before installation of `php70w`.

Comment: Thanks for your idea :) success installed php7 on centos7.                           solve ==>1. yum clear -> 2.yum install yum-plugin-replace -> 3. php-common, php-xml replaced -> 4. install php7

Answer (score 2):

I found easier/safer to rely on Remi's repos http://rpms.famillecollet.com/ instead of webtatic than remove the existing packages - which is also a valid solution.

This is what solved it for me (pick the mirror closest to you):

```
rpm -Uvh http://mirror.innosol.asia/remi/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
yum install php70
yum install php70-php-mysqlnd php70-php-devel php70-php-gd php70-php-mcrypt php70-php-mbstring php70-php-pear php70-php-pecl-imagick php70-php-pecl-zip
```

Note this was needed for a development server